# Infinite scroll browser issues?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am creating an infinite scroll that works with our database.

After much headache and trial and error, I got it working..almost.

I am having a very strange problem that may be easily solved by a more advanced developer.

When I upload my files to the live site and test it out the 1st time, everything works perfectly.

But if I was to refresh this page, or open it up in another window, I get a bug where it loads my ajax query twice... Even If i was to switch tabs..

So after I scroll down to populate the next 10 records, it pulls up that 10 records twice(so 20 records in total). And it does that for the rest of the list.

I am not sure if this is a browser issue or something in my code?
Any help will be appreciated.
**My Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() == jQuery(document).height() - jQuery(window).height()) {

            jQuery('div#loadMore').show();
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "ajax.php?lastCourse="+ jQuery(".wrap:last").attr("id"),
                success: function(html) {
                    if(html){
                        jQuery("#infiscroll").append(html);
                        jQuery('div#loadMore').hide();
                    }else{
                        jQuery('div#loadMore').replaceWith("<center><h1 style='color:red'>End of Content !!!!!!!</h1></center>");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**My AJAX**

```
if ($_GET['lastCourse']) {
$val = $_GET['lastCourse'];
$query = $db -> query ('SELECT * FROM course WHERE IDCourse >"'    .mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['lastCourse']) . '"  ORDER BY IDCourse ASC LIMIT 0, 10');
while($row = $query->fetch()) {
?>
......
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bear in mind that if you scroll down, and refresh, the browser automatically scrolls to the place you were before. As such, this would explain your behavior.

If you'll explain more in detail how do you want to approach this I'll try to help.

Additionally, you don't have a semaphore for ongoing ajax requests (if there's an ongoing ajax request, don't retrieve any more entries). With semaphore your code would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var is_loaded = true;
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() == jQuery(document).height() - jQuery(window).height()) {

            jQuery('div#loadMore').show();

            if (is_loaded)
            {
                is_loaded = false;
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "ajax.php?lastCourse="+ jQuery(".wrap:last").attr("id"),
                    success: function(html) {
                        is_loaded = true;
                        if(html){
                            jQuery("#infiscroll").append(html);
                            jQuery('div#loadMore').hide();
                        }else{
                            jQuery('div#loadMore').replaceWith("<center><h1 style='color:red'>End of Content !!!!!!!</h1></center>");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Adding a semaphore fixed my issue. Thanks for the reply and help!